# Custom Sidebar not showing up. Giving error: ReferenceError: getService is not defined eval

Tags: google-apps-script

Problem:

I have added an item in my menu. But when I click on the sub menu item, I am not able to retrive or render the HTML on my side bar. Instead it gives me an error which says, " ReferenceError: getService is not defined eval"

Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  ui.createMenu('XXX')

      
      .addItem('Test', 'testSidebar')
   
    
    .addToUi();
  
}

function testSidebar () {

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Wip')
    .evaluate()
    .setTitle('Test');
   
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi.showSidebar(html);

}
```

What I am doing wrong over here?

Comment: From what you have shared it is impossible to tell. Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) AND [Minimal-Reproducible-Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then edit your question so we can help you. Help us help you!

Comment: I have tried to explain better.

Comment: When a method is not defined, the error will show what line it happened. Nowhere in your code do I see `getService`. So we still can't even begin to reproduce your issue. Please try harder :). Use steps (1,2,3,4...) It can help in breaking down your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I just fixed the getService to the acutal service name i.e getFacebookService It started to work :) Many Thanks

Comment: Sometimes reading the code line by line is all it takes. Glad you solved it.